# Div popup on all image gallery links

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code?
 I have a image gallery, and I want to add a popup to every image of the gallery, but it only opens on the same image.
I've tried many different examples, and they work most of the time only for one link, not for all the gallery links.

click on the cart icon

[here is my fiddle....](http://jsfiddle.net/tqTcS/43/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){



//Image pop on mouseover
$("#gallery2 a").append('<span id=myspan class=myspanclass><a  id=deleteimg href="#"      class="delete" ></a><a href="#" class="showreranks" id="d" ><img      src="images/insert_to_shopping_cart.png" class="imgOpa" size=20 width=20 border=0></a></span>');

$(this).find('#gallery2 a.showreranks').append('<div id="popupdiv" class="closemediv"><div class="closemediv"><a href=""><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/kyo-tux/aeon/16/Sign-Close-icon.png" width="16"></a></div><div id="list_preview" class="popupcontent"><p>Some Text!</div></div>');




//makes sure when deleting image it does not pops the fancybox
 $('span a').bind('click', function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();

 });

  $(".photo-link").on({

mouseenter: function () {

 $(this).find('span').stop().delay(100).fadeIn(200);
},
mouseleave: function () {
  $(this).find('span').stop(true).fadeOut(0);
 }
   });





 //Popup Div Start
  $(function () {
   $('a.showreranks').click(function () {
     position = $(this).position();
    $('body').append('<div class="overlay"></div>')
    $('#popupdiv').fadeIn(300);
    $('#popupdiv').css('top', position.top + 17);
    return false;
  });
    });

     (function (a) { 
      jQuery.fn.screencenter = function () {
     this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) +            $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) +   $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}  
         })(jQuery);
      //Popup Div End


         }); 
       </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I get a popup on either image when I click on the basket from a fresh load of the fiddle, so not sure what the problem is exactly?

Comment: yea, but the popup should come up on the image clicked. When i click on the 1st image the popup shows on the 2nd image

Comment: Use light box. jquery Light box is a great plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have same id for popup in both images (The id selector is used to specify for a unique element so use classes when you want to repeat styles). So  `$('#popupdiv').fadeIn(300);` applies to the last  popupdiv inside the last image. Use a class `.popupdiv`. Also you dont need to set a top value through JS. Just give top and left value in CSS.

CSS

```
.popupdiv {
  BORDER-BOTTOM: black 1px solid;
  POSITION: absolute;
  BORDER-LEFT: black 1px solid;
  BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fffff2;
  WIDTH: 90px;
  DISPLAY: none;
  MARGIN-LEFT: 0px;
  OVERFLOW: hidden;
  BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid;
  BORDER-RIGHT: black 1px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 3px;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
}
```

JS

```
$('.popupdiv',$(this)).fadeIn(300);
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqTcS/45/)

Update:

Use latest Jquery 1.9+ for `on` to work

For mouseleave

```
$('.popupdiv', $(this)).on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

For click on close

```
$('.closemediv').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.popupdiv').hide();
 })
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqTcS/48/)

Comment: This works great, but how could the open popup close when hover out to click another link  [code] $('popupdiv').hover(
         function () {
           
         }, 
         function () {
           $(this).css({"display":"none"});
         }
     ); [/code]

Comment: Thanks a lot this works great, I just added some code, so when I click on another link, the previous closes before opening new one </br>[link]http://jsfiddle.net/tqTcS/72/

Comment: If you were on the popup div and then move on to another then the mouseleave event fires which hides it.

Comment: exactly, but if the popup does not open on your mouse position and then go  and click another link, i would have to popups open

Comment: Oh saw the fiddle now. You have `$(".popupdiv").hide();` in   `$('a.showreranks').click(function () {`, remove that. Everytime you click all popups hide.

Comment: when I remove it i end up with 2 popups open, also do you know how to make the text in the popup regular text, somehow it got the properties of the a link